# How to add MongoDb check constraint that documents with datetime greater than the current system time cannot be inserted?

Tags: mongodb, constraints, schema

I want to reject bad incoming data to the MongoDb, bad data is data with timestamps in the future

How can I do this using a MongoDb check constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like `{validator:{"$expr": {$lt: ["$timestamp_field", "$$NOW"]}}}` but it's not working. At least not in v5.0.

I submitted a bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-73125

Seems to be acknowledged. Please subscribe/watch to get notifications on progress.

Comment: It's been fixed in v7 and backported to v5.0, 6.0, and 6.3